# How to rewrite the value of an array element in page.tpl.php

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

I'm totally new to PHP programming and modifying the values of Drupal output with php customisations, so sorry if this question seems dumb.

In Drupal 6 I need to rewrite the value of the array element named **image** shown below to strip out all instances of   **../**

From Dev Load and Dev render tabs, the variable I need to change is here

**opengraph_meta** (Array, 16 elements)
(one of the 16 array elements) ---  **image** (String, 45 characters ) **../../../images/spider-veins-before-after.jpg**

From the info I can see under the devel tab with themer info switched on, I think I should be looking to alter it in the variable in page.tpl rather than template.php

Any guidance?

Comment: Suggest you work out why you have ../../../ etc rather than trying to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks Alex, it's because I have put the../../ directives into the image tags. For pages that exist within pseudo subdirectories eg: mywebsite.com/specials/blog/mypost.htm I need the up directory directive to access images that are stored in a folder called images that sits in the root directory of the drupal installation. I've tried a couple of modules to handle that issue but have experienced issues with them in the past, so prefer to avoid them. I'm not sure  if there is a better solution. I need to psuedo sub directories to facilitate conditional block displays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's preg_replace() function and parse through that array and replace the output. Keep in mind you'll need to know a little regex.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

example:

```
<?php
$string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/quick/';
$patterns[1] = '/brown/';
$patterns[2] = '/fox/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[2] = 'bear';
$replacements[1] = 'black';
$replacements[0] = 'slow';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @duckx, my issue is more to do with actually isolating the output string and assigning it to a variable that can be edited before rendering. Since posting I discovered a hook function in the module (og_tag_render_alter) which appears to offer the functionality I need. However, it looks as though I need to create a custom module in order to implement it - just figuring out how to do that :)